# Java convert Byte Array of ASCII values to int

Tags: java, byte, arrays, operator-keyword

After reading a ByteBuffer into b_array I am trying to convert the ascii values to int.

**Output I am expecting is 129** after executing the code as (b_array[] has the decimal equivalents of ascii codes 49,50,59)

Can some one please tell me where am I doing wrong here. I am doing a 0xFF to make it a unsigned value in java and then OR operation to move the bytes.

```
        byte[]  b_array=new byte[3];            
        buffer.get(b_array,0,3);            
        // Contents inside the b_array in ascii code
        //  b_array[0]=49;
        //  b_array[1]=50;
        //  b_array[2]=57;       

        int value=  b_array[2] & 0xFF | (b_array[1] & 0xFF) << 8 | (b_array[0] & 0xFF) << 16;       
        System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Why would you expect 129?  What you're making is a four byte integer, where the three least significant bytes are set to 49, 50 and 59.  This should give  you `49 * 256 * 256 + 50 * 256 + 59`, which is NOT 129.

Comment: Right. Is there any change which I can make in this snippet to achieve 129? as each digit of 1,2,9 corresponds to ascii value of 49,50,59

Comment: To get the characters in the string "129", you need to convert your ascii to characters, either in a string or not, not to integers.  Try an ascii encoding of bytes to a string.

Comment: Yeah, depending on your default encoding, `Integer.parseInt(new String(b_array))` might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current approach is effectively treating the three values as a 24-bit number - effectively 0x313239.

It sounds like you should be converting it into a string, then parsing that:

```
String text = new String(b_array, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII); // "129"
int value = Integer.parseInt(text);
```

Comment: Correct Jon. I did a  int myInt = Integer.parseInt(new String(b_array)); but my code has to parse millions of messages. So it will create a lot of string objects right?

Comment: @JavaEnthusiast It's easy to do without strings too: `(b_array[2]-'0')*100+(b_array[1]-'0')*10+b_array[0]-'0'` You just have to remember that the number characters in ASCII are different from actual numbers, and the difference is `'0'`, or 48 in decimal.

Comment: @biziclop: While you *could* do that, I'd personally say it's far less clear than just creating the strings.

Comment: @JavaEnthusiast: Yes, it will. And they will quickly be garbage collected. You should monitor garbage collection and memory to check that it won't cause a problem, but I'd be surprised if it really became an issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet Absolutely. And I personally wouldn't bother either unless I had hard proof that all those `String` objects do cause a performance problem. I just wanted to clarify that it wasn't OP's approach that was unworkable, just the implementation of it.

Comment: @JonSkeet and biziclop I am parsing an exchange feed. So I can expect about 10 million messages like to be parsed. I think that will definitely impact the performance. Wondering if there is any raw byte manipulation solution

Comment: @JavaEnthusiast: "definitely" sounds awfully strong without evidence - *do* you have any evidence that this is a problem? I've just tried parsing a byte array 10,000,000 times in this way, and it took less than a second on my laptop. Still think there's a problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet Are u iterating thru the same b_array? I believe which will only create one string in JVM from the string pool. running it 10M on different byte arrays might lead to a different performance. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JavaEnthusiast: No, it won't. `new String(...)` will never reuse an existing string object. But just for fun, I created a new byte array for each iteration too... it still only took about a second. Have you *tried* this yet in your code? The simplest way to prove whether or not it's a problem is for you to try it, rather than *assuming* it's going to be an issue.